# Dataframe from sequence of objects

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a nested JSON structure that I decode into the following classes:

```
case class Player(name: Option[String], age: Option[Int])
case class Team(name: Option[String], players: Option[Seq[Player]])

// create dataframe from JSON structure
val teamDF = spark.read
  .option("multiline", true)
  .schema(teamSchema)
  .json("./test.json")
  .as[Team]
  .toDF()
```

I would like to create another dataframe consisting only of the players, where each property on the player is a column.

EDIT:
The below code works, but only for a single value (age). I'm not able to use explode on multiple columns in a single select statement.

```
val playerDF = teamDF.select(explode($"players.age"))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`only one generator allowed per select clause`

explode top level object i.e `players` and use `players.name`, `players.age` to access individual columns.

```
df.withColumn("players",explode($"players")).select("players.name","players.age")
```

Below code is just show how to use `explode` function on multiple columns.

```
df.withColumn("name",explode($"players.name"))
  .withColumn("age",explode($"players.age"))
  .select("name","age")
```